# Listview inside editor not Scroll in text using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new in xamarin forms now am facing issues, am using Listview itemtemplate inside Editor that editor should be multiline but am not scroll the text, it only scrolls the listview not inner text, Please suggest me ideas should be highly appericate.

I tried also Listview this way in my code using Listviewrenderer using Nestedscrollview enabled

Comment: You could solve it by using custom renderer .Check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/80360/editor-inside-scrollview-not-scrolling .